# Hadoop webhdfs Authentication required

Tags: windows, security, hadoop, kerberos, webhdfs

I have configured kerberos security for hadoop-2.6.0 with SASL in windows.

Everything works fine. But webhdfs not working over https protocol.

```
Permission denied when trying to open /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
```

I have just tested with https://hostname:50470/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS

I have set below properties. But still having the same error.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>http/hostname@domain</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
    <value>C:\http.keytab</value>
</property>
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you write out the command you used?

Comment: I used this simple command https ://hostname:50470/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though we change the settings of browser, it will not work. Finally i set the default realm to my domain name using ksetup command. Now it works. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm facing same issue...can you please explain "set the default realm to my domain" what exactly you did?

Comment: yupe in browser I get Permission denied when trying to open /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
....I want to get curl working I'm guessing if browser issue is resolved then curl will work too

Comment: [Network Setup](http://avery.caltech.edu/computing/Network:Setup:Windows) check this for kerberos settings and browser settings.

Comment: Contact you hadoop admin and make sure he have mapped HTTP principal with all hostnames.

Comment: just to confirm all host names means all the nodes in my hadoop cluster? ..sorry I'm not that familiar with networking concepts

Comment: Yes all noes in the hadoop cluster should be mapped with the HTTP principal.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're entering the above url (`https://hostname:50470/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS`) in a web browser. If so, you'll need to configure your browser to access URLs protected by Kerberos.

More detailed instructions are at http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_sg_browser_access_kerberos_protected_url.html for Firefox/Chrome/IE.

The user running the browser must be successfully kinit'd to the cluster's Kerberos server.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i have solved it for firefox but cannot worked for other browsers.